# Создание полупрозрачной Panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на `button` появлялась `panel` поверх всех компонентов. `Panel` должна быть чёрного цвета и полупрозрачная. Как это сделать?

Comment: "Может есть другие варианты?" - другие варианты чего?

Comment: Другие варианты сделать прозрачную текстуру

Comment: Попробуйте отредактировать вопрос - напишите что вам нужно в конечном итоге, а варианты перечислите наравне ниже.

Comment: Может лучше сделать вместо panel форму без рамки и заголовка? У формы то прозрачность задается без дополнительных извращений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить следующий вариант. Накидываем компонентов на форму, затем закидываем `Panel` в нужное место. Затем создаем отдельный класс, который наследует `Panel`, он нам понадобится для дальнейшей работы:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")] // чтобы дизайнер формы работал
public class ExtendedPanel : Panel
{
    private const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;

    public ExtendedPanel()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
    }

    private int _opacity; // прозрачность 

    public int Opacity
    {
        get { return this._opacity; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value > 100) // процентов от 0 до 100
                throw new ArgumentException("Значение должно быть от 0 до 100");
            this._opacity = value;
        }
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    { 
        // Color.Black - вот он наш черный цвет панели полупрозрачный
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(this._opacity * 255 / 100, Color.Black)))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Переходим в дизайнер формы, там где определены наши компоненты. Здесь нам нужно в двух местах изменить значение нашего `panel1`, а именно в методе `InitializeComponent` делаем так:

```
this.panel1 = new ExtendedPanel();
```

И в объявлении полей класса `Form1` тоже ставим свой тип:

```
private ExtendedPanel panel1;
```

В конструктор формы прописываем следующее:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    panel1.Hide(); // скрываем нашу панель изначально
}
```

Добавляем на форму кнопку и вешаем на нее обработчик:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.BringToFront(); // на первый план
    panel1.Opacity = 50; // задаем прозрачность в процентах
    panel1.Show(); // показываем
}
```

Теперь, после нажатия на кнопку будет полупрозрачная панель.

- > Метод [`Color.FromArgb (Int32, Color)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1hstcth9(v=vs.110).aspx) Создает цвет структуры из
  >   указанного `Color`, с новым определенным значением `alpha`. Чтобы
  >   создать непрозрачный цвет, установите `alpha` до 255. Чтобы создать
  >   полупрозрачный цвет, установите `alpha` любое значение от 1 до 254.
- > Метод [`Control.BringToFront`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront(v=vs.110).aspx) помещает элемент управления в начало
  >   z-порядка. Если элемент управления является дочерним для другого
  >   элемента управления, дочерний элемент управления перемещается в начало
  >   z порядка.
- > [`ControlStyles.Opaque`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) - если присвоено значение `true`, элемент
  >   управления отображается непрозрачным, а фон не закрашивается.

Ссылка на источник: [Any trick to use opacity on a panel in Visual Studio Window Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32402532/5275890)

Comment: Работает! Но есть большая проблема. Получается что панель всегда есть и я не могу использовать компоненты программы над которыми висит панель. Также она не отрисовывается как нужно в моей программе поверх всех компонентов, а занимает какие-то рандомные места и закрывает примерно 15% из 100. Пробовал через структуру документа менять положение, а итог один - не дает пользоваться компонентами и грубо говоря ее почти нет. Хотя в отдельном новом проекте все хорошо. В общем странно все это. Спасибо за помощь. Галочку ставлю.