# Почему видно прогрузку/мерцание компонентов?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

На форме есть `panel`с множеством компонентов на ней. Она открывается по нажатию на `button`. Когда открывается видно на долю секунды прогрузку компонентов. Если растягивать форму некоторые компоненты также мерцают. Можно как-то это исправить?

Comment: Видимо, потому что кто-то из "множества компонентов" не поддерживает двойную буферизацию.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать двойную буферизацию, чтобы избавиться от мерцания. В конструктор формы добавить вот такую строку, после метода `InitializeComponent`:

```
this.SetStyle( // где this - это форма
    ControlStyles.UserPaint |
    ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
    ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
    ControlStyles.ContainerControl |
    ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
    ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor |
    ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer
    , true);
```

- > Свойство [`Control.DoubleBuffered`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered(v=vs.110).aspx) - возвращает или задает
  >   значение, указывающее, должна ли поверхность этого элемента управления
  >   перерисовываться с помощью дополнительного буфера, чтобы уменьшить или
  >   предотвратить мерцание.
- > [`ControlStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) - задает стиль и поведение элемента управления.

Comment: Метод в теме  [Создание полупрозрачной Panel](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/652155/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-panel/652193#652193) не использовал. Мне что-то не понятно куда вставлять код?

Comment: Нет, не использую. Нужно чтобы буферизация распространялась на всю форму, а не только на `panel`.

Comment: Вставил так. Правильно? Я что-то не понимаю. И мерцает все равно.`public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SetStyle( // где this - это форма
                ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
                ControlStyles.ContainerControl |
                ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor |
                ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer
                , true);
            PrintDrives();
        }`

Comment: Да, не получается. Обновил предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @River, может быть нужно было делать так, как я говорил изначально? Прикрутить `DoubleBuffer` именно к `Panel`?

Comment: Может быть. Тааак, тогда что теперь делать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56976/discussion-between-denis-bubnov-and-river).